# Uncaught Error: Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received: 27

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have received an odd error which I cannot understand.

The error seem to come from my setState function, which I'm using within a handleCopy().

```
    handleCopy(){
    console.log("godamn");
    this.setState((
      {copied: true}
    ), setTimeout (()=> this.setState({copied: false}), 1500)); 
    //turn copied status to be on, then 1.5seconds later, turn it back off.
  }
```

The error:
[image]

Now, I don't quite understand what it is angry about, and what is this, what seem for me, a random number that it claims I provide instead of a function?

Following is the full code:

**ColorBox.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./ColorBox.css";
import {CopyToClipboard} from 'react-copy-to-clipboard';

class ColorBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      copied: false
    }
    this.handleCopy = this.handleCopy.bind(this);
  }

  handleCopy(){
    console.log("godamn");
    this.setState((
      {copied: true}
    ), setTimeout (()=> this.setState({copied: false}), 1500)); 
    //turn copied status to be on, then 1.5seconds later, turn it back off.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CopyToClipboard text={this.props.background} onCopy={this.handleCopy}>
      <div style={{ background: this.props.background }} className='ColorBox'>
        {/* if copied is true, show class will be added to copy-container. */}
        <div className={`copy-overlay ${this.state.copied && "show"}`} style={{background:this.props.background}}/>

          <div className={`copy-container`}> 
              <div className="box-content">
                <span>{this.props.name}</span>
              </div>

              <div className="More-Txt">
                  <span>more..</span>

              </div>

          <button className="copy-button">copy</button>
          </div>
          
          
      </div>
      </CopyToClipboard>
    );
  }
}
export default ColorBox;
```

**ColorBox.css**

```
.ColorBox {
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
  }

  .More-Txt {
    position: absolute;
    width:fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 2px;
    border: none;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgb(205, 176, 233);
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin: 3px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .copy-button { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    left: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: gray;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

.ColorBox:hover .copy-button {
    opacity: 1;

}
  .box-content { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 8px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

.copy-overlay{
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }

.copy-overlay.show{
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(50);
    position: absolute;
}




  .copy-container { 

  }
```

**Palette.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ColorBox from "./ColorBox";
import "./Palette.css";

class Palette extends Component {
  render() {
    const colorBoxes = this.props.colors.map(color => (
      <ColorBox background={color.color} name={color.name} key={color.name} />
    ));
    return (
      <div className='Palette'>
        {/* Navbar goes here */}
        <div className='Palette-colors'>
            {colorBoxes}
        </div>
        {/* footer eventually */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Palette;
```

**Palette.css**

```
.Palette {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .Palette-colors {
    height: 90%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was indeed with the setState function.

Noticing carefully, my lack of sending a callback function properly was the cause:

```
  handleCopy(){
    console.log("godamn");
    this.setState(({copied:true}),
      () => setTimeout(() => this.setState({copied:false}), 1500)
      );
    //turn copied status to be on, then 1.5seconds later, turn it back off.
  }
```

notice carefuly the second argument to the first this.setState function call.